# Why does Autofac resolution fail even though service is registered?

Tags: c#, autofac

When I call Autofac's .Resolve method, I get an exception stating that my component has not been registered, but I'm not sure why.

The error:

> Exception thrown:
>   'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' in
>   Autofac.dll Additional information: The requested service
>   'Nt.Bot.Sdi.Secure.SdiApiAccess.Login.ISdiLoginApi' has not been
>   registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to
>   provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

I register my service as follows:

```
public void Configure(ContainerBuilder diContainer)
{
    diContainer.RegisterType<SdiLoginApi>().As<ISdiLoginApi>();
}
```

And the configure method above is called in my global.asax.cs. Note that NtDialogContext.DiContainer is a static property:

```
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        new BotDependencyInjectionConfig().Configure(containerBuilder);
        NtDialogContext.DiContainer = containerBuilder.Build();
```

Then I try to load the service as follows. This is where I get the error (I tried the 'generic' versions of Resolve as well):

```
using (var containerScope = NtDialogContext.DiContainer.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var loginApi = (ISdiLoginApi)containerScope.Resolve(typeof(ISdiLoginApi));
}
```

If I use the debugger to inspect the containerScope right before calling .Resolve, I see that my component is in containerScope.ComponentRegistry.Registrations as:

> {Activator = SdiLoginApi (ReflectionActivator), Services =
>   [Nt.Bot.Sdi.Secure.SdiApiAccess.Login.ISdiLoginApi], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership
>   = OwnedByLifetimeScope}

Maybe I misunderstand something about Autofac? Why am I getting an error when trying to Resolve?

I'm using Autofac v4.1.1 that is a dependency of the Bot Builder v3.5.

Comment: can you try var loginApi = containerScope.Resolve<ISdiLoginApi>();

Comment: `NtDialogContext.DiContainer` - where's this from. Have you called `diContainer.Build();` somewhere prior to setting this static property?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `diContainer.RegisterType<SdiLoginApi>().As<ISdiLoginApi>();` does it get hit?

Comment: @hugorgor, same issue I'm afraid.

Comment: @mjwills, yep, that code definitely gets hit. I checked with a breakpoint, but also seems to be the case since the ComponentRegistry.Registration collections does contain the reference. Strange.

Comment: @Alex, sure. I added a bit of code above to indicate where .Build() is called.

Comment: and this code (when removing the new scope):  var loginApi = NtDialogContext.DiContainer.Resolve<ISdiLoginApi>();  If it works, there is a problem with the registration (maybe you should add .InstancePerLifetimeScope() in the registration)

Comment: Can you try adding `.InstancePerLifetimeScope();` to the registration, so it becomes `diContainer.RegisterType<SdiLoginApi>().As<ISdiLoginApi>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

Comment: Does it work if you use `builder.Register(c => new SdiLoginApi()).As<ISdiLoginApi>();` instead? How many times does the `NtDialogContext.DiContainer = containerBuilder.Build();` breakpoint get hit

Comment: @mjwills, thanks, I tried that. The Func inside the "register" never gets called, which is interesting. And containerBuilder.Build() only gets hit once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was not related to Autofac at all. I'll post the answer in case someone runs into the same issue.

We load "plugin" assemblies using MEF (the Managed Extensibility Framework). As part of this loading process we had code that iterated over DLLs in a folder and loaded them into the AppDomain.

```
public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetClientAssembliesRelativeToAssembly(Assembly asm, string subPath = null, string wildcard = "Sdi*.dll")
{
    var path = subPath != null
        ? Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.CodeBase.Substring(8)), subPath)
        : Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.CodeBase.Substring(8));

    foreach (var dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, wildcard))
    {
        yield return Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
    }
}
```

The problem above is that we were using "LoadFile" instead of "LoadFrom". When we use LoadFile, the assembly is loaded directly from where you tell it to. But that lead to the situation where one version of the DLL resided in /bin/ and the other resided in the /Temporary ASP.NET files/ folder.

Then we got into a situation where Autofac compared one type to another (ISdiLoginApi to ISdiLoginApi).  They should have been the same, but were not because one assembly was loaded by MEF (and our "LoadFile" call) and the other by direct reference resided in /Temporary ASP.NET files/. So ISdiLoginApi != ISdiLoginApi and AutoFac.Resolve() failed.

So the solution was to use LoadFrom() in our assembly loading code. That way all assemblies are loaded from the same place, and Autofac can do it's job properly.